# Iterate on a container with two different lexicographical ordering

Tags: c++, iterator, set, containers

I have a container (`set`, `vector`, `vector` etc, but actually I'm interested to set) where each element is a `std::pair` (for example it could be also a `boost::tuple`), is there an easy way to iterate on this container with two different lexicographical ordering?

i.e. my scenario is:

```
std::set<std::pair<int,int> > a;
a.push_back(std::pair(1,3));
a.push_back(std::pair(2,3));
a.push_back(std::pair(4,2));
a.push_back(std::pair(5,2));
a.push_back(std::pair(1,5));
```

I would like to be able to iterate on the set is in this way (and this is the simple part):

```
(1,3)
(1,5)
(2,3)
(4,2)
(5,2)
```

And this other way, using an inverted lexicographical ordering on pair:

```
(4,2)
(5,2)
(2,3)
(1,3)
(1,5)
```

Comment: You may be interested in [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly with the sorted containers from STL like std::set. The comparison function object is set when defining the container and can't be changed afterward.

To solve this you can either use containers that support this directly (like the ones from Boost that Wintermute mentioned) or use a sequence container like vector or list and manually sort it with and appropriate comparison function before you iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: sorry, I did not read the question properly.

Basically once a container is created, the sorting order is hard-coded into it.

The only way is to use another container or these magic boost containers that are taylor made to support that.

Comment: How do you use a comparison functor with std::for_each?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly. You can use the magic Boost.MultiIndex as suggested by Wintermute, or *do it by hand*. That means, as you are interested in `set`, `vector`, or `list`, these are all sorted container, and you can sort it according to your primary order.

Then, you generate a secondary index sorted according to your secondary order. You can use any container, for example a set of pointers to your elements, to have it automatically sorted. But as you will have to explicitely manage additions and deletions, you could also use simply a dynamic array of pointers that you will free and recreate after each modification.